# Is there a way to get google sheets to treat two cell values as the same?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this issue in Google Gheets and was wondering if anyone knows how to resolve it. Basically, I have a sheet that imports into another sheet (I don't have access to the original sheet, so I cannot make changes there, I can only work with the imported data), and the columns that it contains are list of clients, number of orders and revenue. The issue is that on the original sheet some clients have slight variations to their names (for example, "Seventh Bank" and "Seventh Bank LLC") and Google Sheets treats it as two different entities for calculation purposes. Is there a formula that would allow me to tell Google Sheets that "Seventh Bank" and "Seventh Bank LLC" are both the same thing named "Seventh Bank" or is that not something that's possible? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Instead of comparing the names - those values have an Id that you can use, instead? - can you share a public sample worksheet where you show sample data and the desired result?

Comment: This is not bulletproof, but you can use `=REGEXMATCH("Seventh Bank LLC", "Seventh Bank")` return TRUE (because 2nd word is included in 1st)

Answer (score 0):

try substitution:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1; "LLC"; )))
```